# Which Continuous Integration tool are you using?

Tags: .net, tfs, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, teamcity

#### Duplicate:

> - [Continuous Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925/continuous-integration)
> - [Cruise Control .NET alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647621/cruise-control-net-alternatives)

---

I'm planning to start Continuous Integration where I work. I used to use TFS in my previous workplace and before that CruiseControl.Net and before that we wrote our own CI server.

I was wondering what tools are other people are using and why?

I'm mainly concerned with a windows/.Net environment...

Comment: Not only a duplicate, but should be a CW as it's a poll, and doesn't have a definite answer.

Answer (score 15):

Hudson is great - easier to setup than CruiseControl.NET, and produces pretty graphs too.

TeamCity is also easy to setup.

Comment: I agree that [Hudson](https://hudson.dev.java.net/) is wonderful. The setup is a cinch and there is so much flexibility, it's almost overwhelming. Supports MSBuild and NAnt for .NET projects. VCBuild isn't supported per documentation, but I'm sure writing a plugin to do VCBuild instead of MSBuild would be straight forward if you need to do VC++ projects.

Answer (score 8):

I would take a look at the CI Feature matrix, there are literally dozens of tools out there each with their own strengths. Myself, I'm an AnthillPro guy.

[CI Feature Matrix](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix)

Answer (score 3):

We use CruiseControl.NET for .NET environments.  I like the CC Tray application for keeping track of build status.

Answer (score 1):

We used to have two Cruise Control.net servers running about 20 or so builds between them. We've stared moving them all over to a single virtualised TeamCity server, and we're busy adding more (virtual) build agents to reduce build times and reduce queued builds.

I really like the simplicity and user interface of TeamCity. It's easily paid for the licence costs in the time we've saved configuring it. It also allows for easy scaling up of builds over different agents and feeding the output of one build into the input of other builds.

We did look at Hudson and Cruse but it's very difficult to work out which is best from reading brochures and playing with simple test builds.

Answer (score 0):

We use CruiseControl.net with a few custom Ruby scripts carrying out more extensive and custom behaviour at the end of every build.

Currently these are based on the 1.3 version of CC.Net, but with the advent of 1.4 a lot more can be done with the base system and with anything hanging off it.

I wrote [a few blog posts](http://www.spreetree.net/blog/?cat=21) on our CI process which might be of interest.